# What is tested in the Google Play Pre-Launch Security Report?

Tags: google-play-store, security

The Google Play store includes a pre-launch security scan in Pre Launch Report -> Security. I am trying to find out what it is actually testing for. Are there any resources that get into detail on what this scan includes?

The [Learn More](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270#sources) page doesn't say much other than “Each test summary includes the name and description of any security vulnerabilities found in your APK.”